# Deploying node app using jenkins to a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

Using common CI/CD workflow with Jenkins and docker. Deploying app to a server without external internet connection, only jenkins has external internet, so i'm building up node app:

```
npm install
```

in a jenkins pipeline, then deploying it to a docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /var/www/cms

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x ./strapi.sh

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["./strapi.sh"]
```

After `npm install` i'm copying whole directory to a docker container, that step takes approximately 15 minutes to finish up. What's the best way to speed it up?

Answer (score -1):

you should add npm install in the docker file.

it means you will download all the packages modules inside the docker and will not need to copy them from from the outside.

Comment: It doesn't matter in my case, if it's in Dockerfile, because NPM modules will be installed by jenkins anyway. If i wanted to install modules inside a container i would put all installs inside "strapi.sh" file, but my production server doesn't have external internet interface.